# Unable to sort Customer address collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sorting, customer-address

I have an attribute in eav_attribute "**group_id**" for **customer/address**, I am trying to sort my collection by this attribute.What I am doing is.

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$addresses = $customer->getAddressesCollection();
$addresses->addAttributeToSort('group_id', 'DESC');
```

I have also tried following, but nothing is working.

```
$addresses->getSelect()->order('group_id', 'DESC');
```

And

```
$addresses->setOrder('group_id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: what u sure ''group_id' is an attribute of customer/address?

Comment: Yes, it is has  'entity_type_id = 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If **group_id** is **`not`** an attribute of `Customer address type`.

So You cannot short address collection by group then that **is not possible easily**.

For this case,you need to ***add a left join*** with `Customer/address` **resource collection** Class *`Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Collection`*

```
public function addGroupId(){

         $this->joinAttribute('customer_group_id', 'customer/group_id', 'parent_id', 'entity_id', 'left');
  };
```

Then  at **customer model** (**app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php**) and modify **getAddressesCollection()** method

```
public function getAddressesCollection()
{
if ($this->_addressesCollection === null) {
    $this->_addressesCollection = $this->getAddressCollection()
        ->setCustomerFilter($this)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addGroupId()  // add this line at Collection for adding groupid  customer address collection
        ->addAttributeToSort('customer_group_id'); // This line has been added for sorting
    foreach ($this->_addressesCollection as $address) {
        $address->setCustomer($this);
    }
}
return $this->_addressesCollection;
}
```

### If group_id is an attribute of entity_type_id=2

if If group_id is an attribute of entity_type_id=2  mean it is an attribute of customer_address then only need to modify at `getAddressesCollection()`.

Just need to add ->addAttributeToSort('group_id') as per as your share lik [How do I sort all of the multiple shipping addresses associated with a customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74596/how-do-i-sort-all-of-the-multiple-shipping-addresses-associated-with-a-customer)

Comment: Ok, what about this. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74596/how-do-i-sort-all-of-the-multiple-shipping-addresses-associated-with-a-customer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code :

```
$addresses->getSelect()->order('group_id', 'DESC');
```

You can try this :

```
$addresses->getSelect()->order('group_id DESC');
```

It's working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace:

```
$addresses->addAttributeToSort('group_id', 'DESC');
```

With:

```
$addresses->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', 'DESC');
```

Please tell me if it worked.

Comment: Same result, not working